# Backtrack each record to its original state in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to backtrack each single record to find its all states.  The student table contains the updated values only, however student history contains what was the old value for that updated columns.

```
create table student (    
    id number(6) primary key,
    name varchar2(50),
    city varchar2(50),
    address varchar2(100),
    createdDateTime date,
    updatedDatetime date
);

insert into student values(1,'abc1','abc1','abc1','09-Jan-20','12-Jan-20');
insert into student values(2,'pqr','pqr','pqr','09-Jan-20',null);
```

student table-

```
ID      Name    City     Address    Create_time UpdatedTime
1       abc1    abc1     abc1       09-Jan-20   12-Jan-20
2       pqr     pqr      pqr        09-Jan-20   null

create table studentHistory (
    id number(6) ,
    name varchar2(50),
    city varchar2(50),
    address varchar2(100),
    DatetimeCreated date
);

insert into StudentHistory values(1,null,'abc',null,'10-Jan-20');
insert into StudentHistory values(1,'abc',null,null,'11-Jan-20');
insert into StudentHistory values(1,null,null,'abc','12-Jan-20');
```

Student history table-

```
ID  Name    City        Address DatetimeCreated
1   null    abc          null     10-Jan-20
1   abc     null         null     11-Jan-20
1   null    null         abc      12-Jan-20
```

required output will be each stages of single record-

```
ID  Name    City         Address    DatetimeCreated     LastUpdated
1   abc     abc         abc        09-Jan-20            null
1   abc    abc1         abc        09-Jan-20          10-Jan-20
1   abc1    abc1        abc        09-Jan-20          11-Jan-20
1   abc1    abc1        abc1      09-Jan-20       12-Jan-20
2   pqr     pqr         pqr        09-Jan-20           null
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the student history table to insert the entire record of student?  If this is an academic exercise, you need to write an entire block, using a cursor on student history, evaluate each column against student and then hold the output in a temp table or similar.

Comment: Your `student` columns are nullable. How is setting a column to `null`  modelled in history?

Comment: @zynon Putney ll - we cannot change student history table. Only we can do is extract data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reconstruct the history by using logic.  For a given column, the value is the first non-`NULL` value encountered in this order:

1. The value in a particular row.
2. A previous non-`NULL` value in an earlier row for the student
3. The value in `student`

This solves most of the problem.  You then need to bring in the most recent data.  As a query:

```
select sh.id,
       coalesce(sh.name,
                lag(sh.name ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.name
               ) as name,
       coalesce(sh.city,
                lag(sh.city ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.city
               ) as city,
       coalesce(sh.address,
                lag(sh.address ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated),
                s.address
               ) as address,
        s.createdDateTime,
        sh.createdDateTime as updatedDateTime
from studenthistory sh join
     student s
     on s.id = sh.id
union all
select s.id, s.name, s.city, s.address, s.createdDateTime, s.updatedDateTime
from student s;
```

Comment: Instead of lag I used Lead. It resolves my question. However The first stage of record should contain Null value for UpdatedDateTime column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sh.id,
       coalesce(sh.name,
                lag(sh.name ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated desc),
                s.name
               ) as name,
       coalesce(sh.city,
                lag(sh.city ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated desc),
                s.city
               ) as city,
       coalesce(sh.address,
                lag(sh.address ignore nulls) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated desc),
                s.address
               ) as address,
        s.createdDateTime,
        lag(sh.DatetimeCreated) over (partition by sh.id order by sh.DatetimeCreated asc ) as updatedDateTime
from studenthistory sh join
     student s
     on s.id = sh.id
union all
select s.id, s.name, s.city, s.address, s.createdDateTime, s.updatedDateTime
from student s;
```